# How to execute dom manipulation from a subscriber without side effect RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

## Scenario

I have a web component where the DOM manipulation is handled internally and not exposed to the outside world. The outside world has access to a stream that the web component provides.

Every time the web component emits a valid value, internally it should clear the value from the input component. However, this appears to have side effect on the stream.

### Questions

- Why does this happen?
- How can clear subscription be defined without side effect on other subscribers?

### Code

```js
const logExternally = createFakeComponentStream()
  .subscribe(logValue);

function createFakeComponentStream() {
  const inputStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(
      document.querySelector("[name='input']"),
      'keyup')
    .filter(event => /enter/i.test(event.key));

  const valueStream = inputStream
    .pluck('srcElement', 'value');
    
  const logInternally = valueStream.subscribe(logValue);

  const clearOnInput = inputStream
    .pluck('srcElement')
    .subscribe(clearInput);

  return valueStream;
}


function clearInput(input) {
  input.value = '';
}

function logValue(value) {
  if (value) {
    console.log('Success:', value);
  } else {
    console.log('Failed:', value);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.2/Rx.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input" value="" />
```

### Expected Output

```
Success: asdf
Success: asdf
```

### Actual Output

```
Success: asdf
Failed:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the DOM element through the observable streams and one of your subscribers is *mutating* the DOM element, so when the 2nd observer receives the notification and checks the value of the DOM element, it has already been modified.

To avoid this, you need to capture the value before you clear the input.  something like this:

```
const inputStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(
      document.querySelector("[name='input']"),
      'keyup')
    .filter(event => /enter/i.test(event.key))
    .map(event => ({ srcElement: event.srcElement, value: event.srcElement.value }))
    .share();

const valueStream = inputStream.pluck("value");
const logInternally = valueStream.subscribe(logValue);
const clearOnInput = inputStream.pluck("srcElement").subscribe(clearInput);
return valueStream;
```

I made 2 changes:

1. I use `map` to capture the value of the DOM Element early in the stream
2. I use `share` so that this captured value is shared with all subsequent subscriptions to the input stream

These two changes will shield the `valueStream` subscribers from the clearInput mutation.

Comment: I take it from the original code the observable wasn't multicasting and so each stream would evaluate the value of the input independently. Is that correct?

Comment: It was not capturing the value before passing the element to a mutating subscriber. The multi casting was also required so that the value would only be captured once, instead of once per subscriber.